# how to sum only the max value for common prefix inside the array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have array contain string items in scala , each item contain from prefix + || + double value like below :

```
var y = Array("Zara||6.0", "Nuha||4.0","Zara||2.0","Zara||0.1")
```

**what I want to Do :**

i need sum all double value from above array (y(i).split("\|\|")(1)) But if the prefix the duplicated in the array then I only want sum the max value like below  :
for item Zara we have 3 values i want to take the max (in our sample it 6.0)
for item Nuha it unique then i will take it's value (4.0)

**the excepted output is** (6.0+4.0)=10.0

is there are any way to do it in scala rather than using 2 instead loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare your array: extract prefix and values into tuple. Use *foldLeft* for aggregate max elem for each prefix, and sum values

```
val res = y.map(_.split("\\|\\|")).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1).toDouble))
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Double]) { (acc, elem) =>
        val value = acc.get(elem._1).map(math.max(_, elem._2)).getOrElse(elem._2)
        acc + (elem._1 -> value)
      }.values.sum
     
println(res)
```

Comment: Or `y.map(_.split("\\|\\|"))
    .groupBy(r => r.headOption)
    .map{case (k, v) => (k, v.flatMap(_.tail))}` And there you can do whatever you want with the whole collection

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty much in one step (it's three steps technically, but only one specifically addressing your requirement, everything else (split and sum) is kinda a given either way.

```
   y
    .iterator
    .map(_.split("""\|\|"""))
    .groupMapReduce(_.head)(_.last.toDouble)(_ max _)
    .values
    .sum
```

Also ... *do not use vars*. Even if you just putting together a quick sample. Vars are evil, just pretend they do not exist at all ... at least for a while, until you acquire enough of a command of the language to be able to tell the 1% of situations, where you might actually need them. Actually, avoid using `Array`s as much as possible too.